# How to represent concatenation operator (||) in jOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to convert this query to jOOQ but got stuck on the "||" that I use to concatenate the value to the array.

```sql
with recursive nodes(node_key, parent_ids, parent_path) as (
    select node_key, array[node_key] as parent_ids, array[name::text] as parent_path
    from node
    where parent_node_key is null
    
    union all
    select c.node_key, parent_ids || c.node_key, parent_path || c.name::text
    from node c
    join nodes n on n.node_key = c.parent_node_key
)
select * from nodes order by parent_path;
```

jOOQ code that I have done so far:

```java
dsl.withRecursive( name( "nodes" )
                       .fields( "node_key",
                                "parent_ids",
                                "parent_path" ).as(
        select(
            NODE.NODE_KEY,
            array( NODE.NODE_KEY).as( "parent_ids" ),
            array( NODE.NAME).as( "parent_path" )
        )
            .from( NODE)
            .where( NODE.PARENT_NODE_KEY.isNull() )
            .unionAll(
                select( NODE.NODE_KEY,
                        field( "parent_ids" ))
            ) )
) );
```

How do I concatenate the value to the array?

Answer (score 2):

Use the arrayCat function instead of the operator.

https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresDSL.html#arrayCat(T%5B%5D,org.jooq.Field)